# SQL Efficient way to loop through sequential time-series data to identify unique users without double counting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project where I have users that have 'signed up' during a period from Day1 to Day8. However, due to the circumstances of the issue a user can 'sign up' more than once. This results in the same users being able to sign up in Dayx and Dayz. Note: I am using the latest stable version of PostGreSQL for Windows

The goal is to only count the number of unique sign ups for each day while without double counting any users. This means that total sign ups in Day8 need to take into account signups in Days1-Day7 as well.

The solution I have at the moment works technically, but it is very clunky, takes forever to query and does not scale well. Ideally, the SQL query needs to scale for any time period between time x and time y without having to manually write a block of code for each individual time period.

As you can see from my code below it technically gives me the write answer, but is cumbersome, slow and does not scale. Looking for help finding an elegant, scalable solution that does not take 30 minutes to run.

Note: I could write this much more elegantly in Python but am not sure how well Python scales with large datasets stored in RDBMS (ex: Pull all raw data with SQL and then import the CSV into python where a python script will do the calculations instead of doing it in SQL)

```
TABLE DATA:
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| cookie_id | time_created |                      URL                      |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| 3422erq   | 2018-10-1    | https:data.join/4wr08w40rwj/utm_source.com    |
| 3421ra    | 2018-10-1    | https:data.join/convert/45824234/utm_code.com |
| 321af     | 2018-10-2    | https:data.join/utm_source=34342.com          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cookie_id), time_created FROM Data WHERE url LIKE ('%join%') 
AND time_created IN (SELECT MIN(time_created) FROM Data)
GROUP BY time_created
```

--Code to get all unique users in Day1 (5,304 unique users)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cookie_id), time_created FROM Data WHERE url LIKE ('%join%') 
AND time_created IN (SELECT MIN(time_created +1) FROM Data)
AND cookie_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT cookie_id FROM Data WHERE time_created = '2018-10-01')
GROUP BY time_created
```

--Code to get all unique users in Day2 (9,218 unique users)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cookie_id), time_created FROM Data WHERE url LIKE ('%join%') 
AND time_created IN (SELECT MIN(time_created +2) FROM Data)
AND cookie_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT cookie_id FROM Data WHERE time_created BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-02')
GROUP BY time_created
```

--Code to get all unique users in Day3 (8,745 unique users)

Expected & actual results are the same. However the code does not scale and is incredibly slow.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help without knowing what the table structure is, and what the data is. For example you have this `LIKE '%join%'` condition that will make any index useless, but we don't know if there can be multiple URLs a user can join through or you're just taking a shortcut to typing the whole thing. Post the `CREATE TABLE Data` statement and at least a couple of different rows from it.

Comment: @MarcinJ Thanks for the feedback. Added some sample table data.

And yes I need to use 'Like' because I am searching long URL strings for a specific key word that links a user to a certain stage in a process.

Comment: I'm assuming same `cookie_id` can occur multiple times with different URLs, and even with a `%join%` URL on different dates? What data type is `time_created`? How many millions of rows do you have in that table?

Answer (score 1):

So given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    cookie_id text,
    time_created date,
    url text
)
```

(Yes, no indexes)

I generated 5.5 million rows with random 5 [0-9A-F] characters long cookie_ids on a random (`2018-10-01::date + (10*random())::int`) date, with every 100th row having the `https:data.join/....` url while others were some garbage.

Your second query took around 8.5 minutes. This one, on the other hand, took around 0.2s:

```
with count_per_day as
(
    select time_created, count(*) as unique_users from (
        select cookie_id
             , time_created
             , row_number() over (partition by cookie_id order by time_created) occurrence
          from data
         where url like 'https:data.join%'
           and time_created between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-08'
    ) oc
    where occurrence = 1
    group by time_created
)
select time_created, unique_users, sum(unique_users) over (order by time_created) as running_sum
  from count_per_day
```

Again, with no indexes. If you have orders of magnitude bigger counts, an index on `(left(url, 15), time_created, cookie_id)` and change of url condition to `left(url, 15) = 'https:data.join'` dropped it to below 50ms.